# How to work with Multiple Joins without Duplicate Data SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm having an issue working with SQL data where once I have completed muptiple joins I am getting duplicate data.

Here is the code written for

```
SELECT RPPlannedLabor.PeriodHrs, RPPlannedLabor.StartDate, (RPAssignment.WBS1 + ' ' + PR.Name) AS 'WBS1',  RPAssignment.WBS2, EM.FirstName, EM.LastName, EM.TKGroup, (EM.FirstName + ' ' + EM.LastName) AS 'Full Name'
FROM  RPPlannedLabor
LEFT OUTER JOIN RPAssignment
ON RPPlannedLabor.AssignmentID = RPAssignment.AssignmentID
AND RPAssignment.WBS1 IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN EM
ON RPAssignment.ResourceID = EM.Employee
AND EM.Status = 'a'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PR
ON ((RPAssignment.WBS1 = PR.WBS1)
AND (ISNULL(RPAssignment.WBS2,0) = ISNULL(PR.WBS2,0))
AND (ISNULL(RPAssignment.WBS3,0) = ISNULL(PR.WBS3,0)))
AND PR.Sublevel = 'Y'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: what is the specific error, give us an example of the error

Comment: why Excel-vba tag?

Comment: @elddenmedio - duplicate data doesn't raise an error.   TH87 - very hard to tell what your error is if you say duplicate data without showing your data.  Issue is one of your joins is returning more than one row.

Comment: Ask another question, providing sample data, desired results, and a proper database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -  Pardon... the issue? I'm working with Deltek Vision

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to guess your isnull portions in the join is finding a bunch of null fields and cross joining, but thats just a guess.   Data issues like this can't really be solved on a code help forum, best I can do is teach you to trouble shoot.

Run this and get the row count:

```
 SELECT count(1)
 FROM  RPPlannedLabor
```

Run this

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM  RPPlannedLabor
LEFT OUTER JOIN RPAssignment
ON RPPlannedLabor.AssignmentID = RPAssignment.AssignmentID
AND RPAssignment.WBS1 IS NOT NULL
```

Compare with first query...if count increase, your duplicate is on this first join.

Doesn't increase?   Keep iterating, run this:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM  RPPlannedLabor
LEFT OUTER JOIN RPAssignment
ON RPPlannedLabor.AssignmentID = RPAssignment.AssignmentID
AND RPAssignment.WBS1 IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN EM
ON RPAssignment.ResourceID = EM.Employee
AND EM.Status = 'a'
```

Compare to your count above.  Are there more records or is it the same?  more records means this last join we added is causing them.  If not...my guess is this here is causing the duplicates:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN PR
ON ((RPAssignment.WBS1 = PR.WBS1)
AND (ISNULL(RPAssignment.WBS2,0) = ISNULL(PR.WBS2,0))
AND (ISNULL(RPAssignment.WBS3,0) = ISNULL(PR.WBS3,0)))
AND PR.Sublevel = 'Y'
```

If you are joining on fields with isnull functions, odds are there are nulls and potentially more than one...but I might be off as your data issue could be anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for considering this issue.  The duplicates are coming from the LEFT OUTER JOIN PR section listed last in your response.

Comment: @TH87 - somewhat as expected.  If you have 2 rows in PR that have the same WBS1 entry (and sublevel = y) but null for the WBS2 and WBS3 entrees, the join gets evaluated as "wbs1 = wbs1 and 0 = 0 and 0 = 0 and sublevel = 'Y'.  Not a code solution here, you need to go back to the requirements phase and determine a correct join to PR.

Comment: I assumed with a left join it would just grab one of the PR Rows, not both.  I think what you have listed is my exact issue.

Comment: @TH87 - Left join retains the row in the left table if it's not found in the table it's joined to (inner join would drop the row)...both inner and left joins behave the same when there are multiple rows found that meet the join condition

Comment: So if I have one row in the left table (RPAssignment) and 2 Rows in PR that match, I can't select the one row from RP Assignment and the first row in PR?

Comment: You would need logic to differentiate it, or you can join to a subquery to make it distinct.  Instead of left join pr on...   use left join (select distinct rows from table) pr on ... instead.